# Bootstrap UI Pagination - current page is set to zero when DOM is loaded

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap UI Pagination to paginate search results page and also want to store query, current page and page size in URL so it can be shared by users:

http://localhost:39519/#?q=security&limit=10&page=2

The problem is that when I browse link that, the 2nd page is displayed but after a while (when DOM is loaded) current page get reset and first page is 
displayed.

Here is plunker but I dont know how to simulate change in URL.

```
<uib-pagination ng-show="total" direction-links="false" boundarylinks="true" items-per-page="pageSize" total-items="total" ng-change="pageChanged()" ng-model="currentPage"></uib-pagination>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RhxoYOyDjwyoLbMOFtct?p=info

Comment: A wild guess is because you defined to call `pageChanged()` on *any* change. `ng-change="pageChanged()" ` - what is this supposed to do? Are you sure this is required when using `uib-pagination`?

Comment: I need to handle somehow the event when page changes, is it possible otherwise?

Comment: Maybe - please provide a working plunker.

Comment: My solution was to create a hidden input that holds the current page and work the jQuery from this